# Best Practice for Instrumenting RACSignal

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I've been tasked with adding some instrumentation logic to an app to track the latency of various API calls.  I'm struggling to come up with a clean, non side-effecting way to add timing instrumentation to methods that return RACSignal's (deferred execution API calls).

### Considerations

- Using ReactiveCocoa @ 1.9.5 (can't upgrade at the moment)
- Using [Parse-RACExtensions](https://github.com/kastiglione/Parse-RACExtensions) @ 0.0.2
- I'd prefer to set up timings at the ViewModel layer as opposed to modifying Parse-RACExtensions.  This is because the VM has extra info I'd like to log, like query parameters, and I don't need every API call instrumented.
- Only record timings upon receipt of a `completed` event
- In the spirit of painless instrumentation, the burden on the caller should be as small as is practical

### Attempted Solution

The only thing I've been able to come up with is to create a concrete RACSubscriber subclass that that handles the timer logic.  Besides the nasty subclass, this obviously isn't ideal as it requires an explicit `subscribe:`, which in turn requires a `replay` on the source signal.  Additionally, there is a burden on the caller as they have to at least refactor to get a temporary handle to the signal.

```
@interface SignalTimer : RACSubscriber

@property (nonatomic) NSDate *startDate;

@end

@implementation SignalTimer

- (void)didSubscribeWithDisposable:(RACDisposable *)disposable
{
    [super didSubscribeWithDisposable:disposable];

    self.startDate = [NSDate date];
}

- (void)sendCompleted
{
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startDate];
    NSLog(@"Time elapsed: %f", duration);

    [super sendCompleted];
}

@end
```

Usage would look like this:

```
- (RACSignal*)saveFoo:(Foo*)fooParseObj {
    RACSignal *save = [[fooParseObj rac_save] replay]; // Don't forget replay!
    [save subscribe:[[SignalTimer alloc] initWithName@"Saving the user's foo object"]];
    return save;
}
```

Obviously, I'm not happy with this implementation.

### Final Thoughts

Ideally, I'd like a chain-able method like this, but I wasn't sure how to accomplish it/if it was possible to handle a cold signal without nasty side-effects inside a category method (like calling `replay` on the receiver).

```
[[[fooParseObj rac_save] logTimingsWithName:@"Saving the user's foo object"] subscribeNext:...];
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think I was making this way harder than it needed to be. The following category solution seems much more idiomatic, but I'd love any feedback.

```
@interface RACSignal (Timing)

- (instancetype)logTimingWithName:(NSString*)name;

@end

@implementation RACSignal (Timing)

- (instancetype)logTimingWithName:(NSString*)name
{
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

        NSDate* startDate = [NSDate date];

        return [self subscribeNext:^(id x) {
            [subscriber sendNext:x];
        } error:^(NSError *error) {
            [subscriber sendError:error];
        } completed:^{
            NSTimeInterval duration = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
            NSLog(@"%@: %f sec", name, duration);

            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }];
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Looks good to me! Though you don't need a new `NSDate` for calculating the delta—just use `startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow` and negate it.